# Surface integral in a cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let

$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = \left({-x\,{\bf i}-3\,x\,y^2\,{\bf j}+z\,{\bf k}}\right).$$

so then the $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}= -6yx$

then

$$V = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\le z\le 2xy,~ x^2+y^2\le {1}\right\},$$

I want to evaluate the surface integral:

$$\displaystyle\iint_{S}\left(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\right)dS$$

I know that $S=\delta V$

So parametrization is

$$x = r\cos(\theta)$$
$$y=r\sin(\theta)$$
$$z = z$$

and then $0 \le \theta \le2\pi$ and $0\le z \le 2xy$
 and $r=1$

But how do I calculate the integral?

Answer (score 1):

We can use divergence theorem, and we have

$$\displaystyle\iint_{S}\left(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\right)dS)=\iiint_V \nabla\mathbf{F}\,dV$$

with $\nabla\mathbf{F}= -6yx$.

By [**cylindrical coordinates**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html#targetText=Cylindrical%20coordinates%20are%20a%20generalization,for%20the%20other%20two%20coordinates.) the set up should be

$$\iiint_V \nabla\mathbf{F}\,dV=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1dr\int_0^{2r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta}-6r^3\cos\theta \sin \theta \,dz$$

Comment: Okey but what are the limit values of that integral then

Comment: @vvv I'll add something on that.

Comment: What is the answer because I got some random answer $(-6*\pi*sin^2(\theta))$

Comment: @vvv It seems equal to $\pi/2$ see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28-6r%5E3cos+t+sin+t%29+dz+dr+dt+z%3D0..%282r%5E2+cos+t+sin+t%29+r%3D0..1+t%3D0..2pi).